# Xamarin Ui Test -> Compatible with Android target version 9.0 (28)

Tags: android, xamarin, adb, xamarin.uitest

I've got an Android project with the target to Android 9 (PI) -> SDK Platform 28.

I would like to write Xamarin UI tests to my project, but unfortunatelly I get the error:

```
System.Exception: 'The running adb server is incompatible with the Android SDK version in use by UITest: 
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

You probably have multiple installations of the Android SDK and should update them or ensure that your IDE, simulator and shell all use the same instance.  The ANDROID_HOME environment variable can effect this.'
```

I use following versions:

- Target Platform: Android 9
- Xamarin.UITest 3.0.0 (currently the latest)
- ADB 1.0.41

Before I used the ADB 1.0.39, but I replaced it by the version 1.0.41 after the error occurred.

Does Xamarin UI Test currently works with the target platform Android 9 at all?

What are compatible versions?

Comment: You have multiple `adb` versions running. If you have replaced an older one but still have it running, shutdown VS, emulators, etc... and use `adb kill-server` (or just reboot your PC/Mac) . Also double check that you only have one version installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :)

It was really a problem with different ADB versions...

The concrete problem was, that the ADB version within Visual Studio was different from my version in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`.

Following solution helped:

1. Open the "Package Manager Console" within Visual Studio.
2. Update ADB to the latest version (within the console): `dotnet tool update --global AndroidSDK.PlatformTools.ADB`
3. Download the same version as updated from [the ADB git-hub project](https://github.com/awake558/adb-win)
4. Rename the old "platforms-tools" folder within `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\` and copy the downloaded "platforms-tools" folder into the Sdk directory.
5. Restart the computer.

The tests started after these steps successfully.

PS: The "platforms-tools" folder can be found using the "adb version" command within the windows console.